# Magento Customer Email Activiation

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

Trying to import customers from an old site to new, the idea behind the migration is to not cause any down time and have the site work exactly as before so i need the customers that were email activated to be so on the new site.

I've looked in `customer_entity_int` and in the `customer_attribute` table but too no avail, could someone tell me what magento does behind the scenes when a customer clicks the link in the email activation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the customer entity `is_active` is set to **1**. There is also an attribute `confirmation` for customers that is set to **null**.

Check `Mage_Customer_AccountController::confirmAction` and you can see what Magento actually does when the link is clicked.
On line 600 the following is done

```
try {
   $customer->setConfirmation(null);
   $customer->save();
}
```

the `setConfirmation` part translates to the attribute `confirmation` which is stored in the table `customer_entity_varchar`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but all of the customers have is_active set to one but when trying to log in I get the email not activated thing

Comment: @RobertPounder I was too quick. See edit :)

Comment: Ah nice one don't suppose you could give me the details on the `confirmation` and how it is related in db?

Comment: Depends on how you're importing it but as long as you leave the field empty it should be fine

Comment: As stated in original question its not :P!

Comment: And can't find the entity-customer relationship :(

Comment: customer_entity.entity_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id

Comment: Add that bit to the original answer to help other users bud :p

Comment: You mean a query to get or set the confirmation?

Comment: the fact it uses `customer_entity_varchar`

Comment: sorry, not too sure what you mean but updated my answer

Comment: Yeh what you changed was fine, it just wasn't uniform with the rest of the customer attributes to be in the varchar table